# Existence of bump functions with certain bound on Fourier transform of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Can we find a function $\sigma\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ with $\sigma(\tau)=1$ for $|\tau|\leq 1$, $\sigma(\tau)=0$ for $|\tau|>2$, and
$$
\int|\widehat{\sigma^{(n)}}|\leq 2^n
$$
for each $n\geq 0$?

I am asking this because I need to find such functions for a proposition in my thesis.

Comment: If you're writing a thesis, you must have some thoughts, some things you've tried? Also, do you really want $\le2^n$ or is $\le C2^n$ enough?

Comment: $C^n$ would be enough.

Comment: Why do we want such a bump function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

From Sobolev embeddings (or fundamental theorem of calculus) and your integral condition one would have for every $x$
$$
|\sigma^{(n-1)}(x)| \leq C^{n}
$$
and so $\sigma$ is analytic, and so cannot be compactly supported.